# Create an Array of Favorite fruits Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have the following assessment which is to Create Array of Favorite Food items object in data.json file.

The Array of Objects should have the following fields :

- Name
- Type
- Price

After writing the JSON data, this file should be imported in loopobject.js.

I tried the above request with the below **data.json**

```
{
 "food":[
    {
      "Name":"Apple",
      "Type":"fruit",
      "Price":100
    },
    {
      "Name":"pizza",
      "Type":"italian",
      "Price":370
    },
    {
      "Name":"Burger",
      "Type":"Mac&Cheese",
      "Price":310
    },
    {
      "Name":"salad",
      "Type":"Veg",
      "Price":50
    }
  ]
}
```

And with **loopobject.js**

```
var json = require('./data.json');

json.forEach(function(object) { console.log(object.Name); });
```

and the Schema is:

```
const schema = Joi.array().min(3).has({
    Name: Joi.string().required(),
    Type: Joi.string().required(),
    Price: Joi.number().required(),
});
```

On submitting the above **data.json** and **loopobject.js** I get:

`ValidationError: "value" must be an array`

I am not sure how to edit the **data.json** to make it Array of Objects, as for as I can think the data.json has array of objects.
Can someone help fix the issue on **data.json** and **loopobject.js**?

Please note I can't edit the JSON schema

Comment: data.json doesn't contain an array of objects, it contains an object with a key named "food" and an array of objects as it's value. Also what are those quotes? There should only be `"` in a JSON file.

Comment: if this is the actual data your data.json file has, I can see many ”s where there should be  " s

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: If a question has these tags: `javascript`, `arrays` and `object`, there is a very high probability that it's been already answered here on SO. If you can't find a similar question, then look again at your code and find an obvious typo. In this case it seems to be the latter ;) Fix all the typos and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: The " quote change is because of the notepad. I copied code from notepad to the site. Please ignore that.

Comment: I tried searching, was not able to find anything relevant to the schema I searched for.

Comment: I was not able to figure out the Schema with `Joi.array().min(3).has({` what does `.has()` means, quick internet search does not give me an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json` is an object and has `"food"` named array. If you want to have just array, please change your JSON like this:

```
[
    {
      "Name":"Apple",
      "Type”:”fruit”,
      "Price":100
    },
    {
      "Name”:”pizza”,
      "Type”:”italian”,
      "Price”:370
    },
    {
      "Name”:”Burger,
      "Type”:”Mac&Cheese”,
      "Price”:310
    },
    {
      "Name”:”salad”,
      "Type”:”Veg”,
      "Price”:50
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

`json` is not an `array`, you want to use `json.food`.

```
var json = require('./data.json');

json.food.forEach(function(object) { console.log(object.Name); });
```

Comment: The validation was not focused on the javascript part of the question. so used a simple one, the use of `json.food.forEach` is moot now as I was able to get the data.json from Murat Yildirm

Answer (score 0):

sure its not an array its an object with key and array pair {food:[array]}
first you need to extract that array part and then you can perform the array operations

Comment: The focus of the question is on the JSON file and not on the JS file, so used simple JS. Thanks for the answer, got what I want.